# How to compress Video in react-native using ffmpeg

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg, video-compression

I have `react-native` application in this app, I need to upload video which have large amount of size.
So, How to compress video and reduce it's size using https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg this package.

Comment: It says that it’s not maintained, did you try https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit?

Comment: I've checked it didn't find any compression related code in that package.

Comment: You can use ffmpeg-kit. Try to understand documentation.

Comment: compression should be from the server side. not from the front. Also, react-native does not have any maintained library for video compression. I tried but compression time is far more than uploading it.